# React Hook redraw component trees on every page resize

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using [usehooks-ts](https://usehooks-ts.com) and I made a hook that would check what breakpoints are currently active based on window size.

```
export const useScreenBreakpoint = () => {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const windowWidth = useDebounce(width, 500);
  const [activeBreakpoint, setActiveBreakpoint] =
    useState<Record<keyof typeof config.theme.extend.screens, boolean>>();
    
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveBreakpoint(getActive());
  }, [windowWidth]);

  const getActive = () => {
    const screens = config.theme.extend.screens;

    const matches = Object.entries(screens).reduce((results, [name, size]) => {
      const mediaQuery = `(min-width: ${size})`;

      results[name] = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches;

      return results;
    }, {} as Record<string, boolean>);

    return matches;
  };

  const isBreakpointActive = useCallback(
    (bp: keyof typeof config.theme.extend.screens) => {
      return activeBreakpoint?.[bp] || false;
    },
    [activeBreakpoint]
  );

  return {
    activeBreakpoint,
    isBreakpointActive,
  };
};
```

Now, this works great, and I do get my breakpoints. the problem is I am calling this hook in a component like this :

```
  const { activeBreakpoint } = useScreenBreakpoint();
  return isBreakpointActive('lg') : <div>lg</div> : <div>notLg</div>
```

the issue is, this hook make my component redraw on every screen resize, so when I put my real component, React stop working as there is to many redraw requests.

I don't understand how I can make this work in a more lightly way.
`isBreakpointActive('lg')`
should be recalculate only when my debounced `windowWidth` is changed. but right now, it is permanently recalculated and keep reload all my component trees.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** `const { width } = useWindowSize();` - this forces the component to re-render on every size change event. Since the callback function in `window.addEventListener("resize", callback)` is not throttled. You can rewrite the `useWindowSize` hook.

In the [source](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-window-size) -

Change

```
useEventListener('resize', handleSize)
```

To

```
const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
      setWindowSize({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      });
    }, interval);

useEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleSize)
```

**Original answer**

You can rewrite the useWindowSize hook as `const { width } = useWindowSize(500);` passing the interval.

In general, when listening to window size changes, `state` only needs to be updated inside the debounce function. You can also move the breakpoint logic inside the debounce function.

Example ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-pine-9f9f62?file=/src/index.js)) with inline debounce function for more clarity -

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth
});

const [isBreakpointActive, setIsBreakpointActive] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
    setDimensions({
      height: window.innerHeight,
      width: window.innerWidth
    });
    setIsBreakpointActive(window.innerWidth > 300);
  }, 1000);

  window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
  };
}, []);

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (_) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout((_) => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}
```

You can see in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-pine-9f9f62?file=/src/index.js), rerenders are debounced.

Comment: hey thanks, yeah, I made a similar hook and it worked, but I wonder how to solve without remaking what the library provide

Comment: See my update. You need to rewrite `useWindowSize` or not use it.